# how to enable Auto Routing in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, auto, codeigniter-4

I want auto routing in codeignitor 4 but don't know how to do it.

As said in the Routes.php file, I have set the "setAutoRoute" to true and also set $autoRoutesImproved to true in "app/Config/Feature.php" but always show 404 error.

`app/Config/Routes.php`

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

`app/Config/Feature.php`

```
public bool $autoRoutesImproved = true;
```

I want URL to be like http://localhost/codeigniter4/pages
"pages" is my new controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://localhost/codeigniter4/pages`

The route above would mean:

- `codeigniter4` - *(URI segment 1)* - Is the Controller name.
- `pages` - *(URI segment 2)* - Is the method name.

---

You got it wrong because you were expecting "pages" to be the controller's name, which isn't the case.

---

[Auto Routing (Improved)](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/routing.html#auto-routing-improved)

> When no defined route is found that matches the URI, the system will
> attempt to match that URI against the controllers and methods when
> Auto Routing is enabled.

[URI Segments](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/routing.html#uri-segments)

> The segments in the URL, in following with the Model-View-Controller
> approach, usually represent:
>
> ```php
> example.com/class/method/ID
> ```
>
> 1. The first segment represents the controller class that should be invoked.
> 2. The second segment represents the class method that should be called.
> 3. The third, and any additional segments, represent the ID and any variables that will be passed to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Set the routes in `app\config\routes.php`:

```php
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

You also need to change the property `$autoRoutesImproved` to false in `app/Config/Feature.php`:

```php
public bool $autoRoutesImproved = false;
```