# Why controller under admin subdirectory not found?

Tags: codeigniter-4

In codeigniter  4.3.7   I created new controller file under subdirectory app/Controllers/admin/Category.php with defined :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\admin; // Not sure - is it correct ?

class Category extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {    
        echo '<pre>::Category::'.print_r(-1,true).'</pre>';
        return view('admin/categories/index', []);
    }
```

But urls

```
http://localhost/CIProducts/admin/categories/index
```

not opens  my controller, as I expected and returns 404 error

while url

```
http://localhost/CIProducts
```

returns default homepage

Also I added in file Routes.php line :

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

In .env file I modified line :

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

But on homepage I still see :

```
Environment: production
```

Can It be that I need to clear cache anyway or why url does not work ?

**EDITED PART 1 :**
I got the issue is that as my url has “/admin/”, so setAutoRoute does not work.
So I removed setAutoRoute from “app/Config/Routes.php” and now it has lines :

```
<?php

use CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection;

/**
 * @var RouteCollection $routes
 */
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index'); // This link works ok

$routes->get('products-by-category', 'ProductsByCategory::index');  // This link works ok

$routes->get('admin/category/index', 'Category::index');  // This link DOES NOT works with 404 error

// $routes->get('admin/category/index', 'admin\Category::index'); // uncommented THAT RETURNS 404
```

With controller in file app/Controllers/admin/Category.php ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share your `Routes.php` settings.

Comment: Why would you expect `http://localhost/CIProducts` to point to a Controller `app/Controllers/admin/Category.php` with `$routes->setAutoRoute(true);`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to enable Auto Routing in CodeIgniter 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663226/how-to-enable-auto-routing-in-codeigniter-4)

Comment: Please read EDITED PART 1

Comment: Can we confirm that `http://localhost/CIProducts` is your `base_url()` ?

Comment: Yes in .env  app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/CIProducts/'